# Show or hide caret icon on bootstrap4 dropdown based on dropdown menu present or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show or hide caret icons based on menu items is present or not. if menu items present show caret icon else hide it. i am using bootstrap4 and in my case dropdown menu items will by dynamically generated.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;!important
}
```

Above code removes caret symbol but how to show/hide it based on the menu in dropdown present or not ?

```css
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide Dropdown button when list is opened and show it when list has been closed?

Comment: do you mean that the button as to be icon and you want to hide if no items inside??

Answer (score 2):

Use `.hide()` if no items inside `$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').length==0`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if($('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').length==0 )
  {
   $('.fas.fa-shopping-cart').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">list<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Only css use `only-child:`**

```css
.dropdown button:only-child .fas.fa-shopping-cart{
display:none;
}
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">list<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
     
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: hey... that what you mean??

Comment: thanks for your reply.that what i was looking for. but can't we do this without jquery or javascript, i mean by using pure css.

Comment: hey I found solution only css

Comment: But that's not working. if you remove all anchor tags within div class dropdown menu,caret icon on the button should get removed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class saying `.hidden` and add display none property to it like.

```
.hidden {
display:none !important
}
```

and in your JS do this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


var hasElement = $(".dropdown-menu" ).has("a");

   hasElement.length == 0 ? $(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("hidden") : $(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("hidden")
});
```

Comment: @GertArnold some of them, I will just check them and edit them cause you for sure know this platform better than me