# How to hide caret icon in dropdown if no data is present in dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement where i want to hide the caret icon in the bootstrap dropdown if dropdown-menu is empty. I am using bootstrap 4. below snippet explains the problem statment clearly. I am looking for pure css solution.

```css
.dropdown-menu:empty{
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none !important;
}
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!--  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see i have commented anchor tags inside dropdown-menu. so now the dropdown-menu tag is empty. so i want to only hide caret symbol present in dropdown button using pure css. I have used inner css to achieve this but not sure  what mistake i have done.

**Basically if dropdown-menu(div tag) is empty i want to hide caret symbol,else show caret symbol on button.**

Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show or hide caret icon on bootstrap4 dropdown based on dropdown menu present or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167912/show-or-hide-caret-icon-on-bootstrap4-dropdown-based-on-dropdown-menu-present-or)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `:only-child` selector.

```css
.dropdown-menu .caret:only-child{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a href="">Lorem</a>
  <span class="caret">v</span>
</div>
```